# spring data elasticsearch dynamic multi tenant index mismatch?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, multi-tenant, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am experimenting with spring data elasticsearch by implementing a cluster which will host multi-tenant indexes, one index per tenant.

I am able to create and set settings dynamically for each needed index, like

```
public class SpringDataES {

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchTemplate es;

    @Autowired
    private TenantIndexNamingService tenantIndexNamingService;

    private void createIndex(String indexName) {
        Settings indexSettings = Settings.builder()
                        .put("number_of_shards", 1)
                        .build();
        CreateIndexRequest indexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(indexName, indexSettings);
        es.getClient().admin().indices().create(indexRequest).actionGet();
        es.refresh(indexName);
    }

    private void preapareIndex(String indexName){
        if (!es.indexExists(indexName)) {
            createIndex(indexName);
        }
        updateMappings(indexName);
    }
```

The model is created like this

```
@Document(indexName = "#{tenantIndexNamingService.getIndexName()}", type = "movies")
public class Movie {

  @Id
  @JsonIgnore
  private String id;
  private String movieTitle;
  @CompletionField(maxInputLength = 100)
  private Completion movieTitleSuggest;
  private String director;
  private Date releaseDate;
```

where the index name is passed dynamically via the SpEl

`#{tenantIndexNamingService.getIndexName()}`

that is served by

```
@Service
public class TenantIndexNamingService {
  private static final String INDEX_PREFIX = "test_index_";

  private String indexName = INDEX_PREFIX;

  public TenantIndexNamingService() {
  }

  public String getIndexName() {
    return  indexName;
  }

  public void setIndexName(int tenantId) {
    this.indexName = INDEX_PREFIX + tenantId;
  }

  public void setIndexName(String indexName) {
    this.indexName = indexName;
  }
}
```

So, whenever I have to execute a CRUD action, first I am pointing to the right index and then to execute the desired action

```
tenantIndexNamingService.setIndexName(tenantId);
movieService.save(new Movie("Dead Poets Society", getCompletion("Dead Poets Society"), "Peter Weir", new Date()));
```

My assumption is that the following dynamically index assignment, will not work correctly  in a multi-threaded web application:

```
@Document(indexName = "#{tenantIndexNamingService.getIndexName()}"
```

This is because TenantIndexNamingService is singleton.

So my question is how achieve the right behavior in a thread save manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go with an approach similar to the following one proposed for Cassandra:

- https://dzone.com/articles/multi-tenant-cassandra-cluster-with-spring-data-ca

You can have a look at the related GitHub repository here:

- https://github.com/gitaroktato/spring-boot-cassandra-multitenant-example

Now, since Elastic has differences in how you define a Document, you should mainly focus in defining a request-scoped bean that will encapsulate your tenant-id and bind it to your incoming requests.

Comment: I have proceeded with an implementation at a recent project involving Elastic. Having a dynamic index using SpEL is working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I create a RequestScope bean to hold the indexes per HttpRequest

[how does singleton bean handle dynamic index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72146757/how-does-singleton-bean-handle-dynamic-index)