# How to access request attributes in SpEL for spring data elastic search

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-elasticsearch, spring-el

I need to use dynamic index per request in spring data elastic search. I got it working by creating a @RequestScope object

[how does singleton bean handle dynamic index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72146757/how-does-singleton-bean-handle-dynamic-index)

I am trying to get it working without creating @RequestScope object. I set the attributes in request. But I don't know to read it out in SpEL

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        httpRequest.setAttribute("indexName", "indexA");


@Document(indexName = "#${request.getAttribute('indexName')}", createIndex = false) --not working
public class MyDocument{
```

I also try @Document(indexName = "#${@request.getAttribute('indexName')}", createIndex = false)

Comment: That will never work... How should elasticsearch know while starting how to create an index? There is no request at the moment that information is needed...

Comment: It can get the value from environment @Document(indexName = "#{@environment.getProperty('indexName')}", createIndex = false). Or from @RequestScope bean @Document(indexName = "#{@indexConfig.getAIndexName()}", createIndex = false) I am wondering if it can get it from some predefined request bean.

Comment: No it cannot. The environment is availabe during startup, as that is static. So no trying to get that from anything other then staticly available (request scoped or the request for instance) will simply not work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to get this into a SpEL expression for the `@Document` annotation you'd better get the name for the index from the request in the function where you want to use Spring Data Elasticsearch methods - I don't just at them moment with which parameter you would get this.

Then use this name to create a `IndexCoordinates` object with that name and pass this as parameter to the `ElasticsearchOperations` method you use.